# QT--OpenMP run time error SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, qt, openmp, segmentation-fault

Why this code generate SIGSEGV exception? I use QT Creator, C++, Openmp.

```
 // myObj : a class name  
    vector <myObj> objVector;
    .......    
    void MainWindow::drawScreen()
    {
        omp_set_num_threads(objVector.size());
        #pragma omp parallel private (objVector)
        {
            int id = omp_get_thread_num();
            if(id > 0) {
                bool collision = false;
                int i = id-1;            
                objVector[i].update();
            }
        }
        this->repaint();
    }
```

In myObj class :

```
void myObject::update() {

    int x = this->X; **// when I run debugging, SIGSEGV occurs this line!!!!!!!**
    int y = this->Y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `private` clause invokes a *default-constructor* for *class-type* variables. In other words, each of your threads operates on a *new* (empty) instance of `std::vector` initialized through its default-constructor.
For a *copy-construction* of the vector you should use the `firstprivate` clause:

```
#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(objVector)
//                   ~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Nonetheless, I suppose you really meant to make this variable a `shared` one:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(objVector)
//                   ~~~~~^
```

Comment: I shouldn't share objVector, because each thread can change it's index. And other thread don't know this. Only master thread should know this.

Comment: @Sdn base on the code you posted I don't see any concurrent access to same element under given index, hence I suppose you need not copy the vector to all threads, but it's up to you